# springboot kafka onApplicationEvent

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I have a Springboot application which has `KafkaConfig` component that produces and consumes Kafka messages. I also have a DB connectionpool manager that initializes the DB pool and creates DB connection. This is not managed by Spring and it is a Java application. I have this connectionpool code bundled in jar. This connectionpool is initialized by CP class implementing `ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent>` inside the Springboot application. Now, I am trying to get Kafka bootstrap server information from the database using the code initialized by the connectionpool. How can I make sure my beans inside `KafkaConfig` is initialized after the CP class?

```
@Component
public class Startup implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {
  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(final ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
   // connection pool getting initialized...
    return;
  }
}
```

This is the repository class that fetches the bootstrap server information from the database

```
@Repository
public class Repo {

   public string getKafkaServer(){
     //Uses the ConnectionPool initialized by Startup class to get the 
     //bootstrap sever information.
   }

}
```

This is the Kafka Config class

```
@Component
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfig {

@Autowired
Repo repo;

@Bean
public consumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory(){
  String bootstrapServer = repo.getKafkaServer();
 //The bootstrapServer is coming as null and this code executes before the 
 //Startup class gets initialized. 

}      
}
```

Any idea on how to get the `KafkaConfig` execute after the Startup code gets loaded?